# Is it possible to use a different navigation menu on some cms pages in magento

Tags: magento, menu, navigation, content-management-system

Is it possible to use a different navigation menu on some cms pages in magento?
And how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a developer you can create (duplicating the which one is in use) one theme that does not show top menu but show your custom menu.
Then when you create a new CMS page in the tab design you can choose your new theme for that specific CMS page.